# using python to obtain objects in an image

Tags: python, image-segmentation

I have this picture. I need to identify the animal in this picture as shown using an image processing algorithm. I'm thinking of using Python for this. But I don't know which algorithm to use and I don't know where to start. Where should I start?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ3nU.png)

Comment: Hi emrcnort, welcome to StackOverflow. This question will probably get flagged as too broad, or as opinion-based. Read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask to get a better understanding of the type of questions that are well-received here.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start is fast.ai.  You will find the videos you need and the code. You can do it on any computer, even a cheap laptop.  You will also want to look into LIME model explanations for image classifiers.